# Apache .htaccess timestamp

Tags: apache-2.2, cache

I'm trying to do some cache mechanism where I create cache files in php that have names like: test_page_20110122_23.html (test_page_[php date('Ymd_G)].html)

The plan is to serve these files without php, strictly by using only apache (or later nginx).
But in order to do that I have to write a rewrite rule that has the current date and time variables, eg:

RewriteCond /cache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} _ {Ymd}*{G}.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/$1*{Ymd}_{G}.html [L]

The only problem that I have is how to get these time variables in .htacces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in apache using mod_rewrite like this

```
RewriteCond /cache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}_%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MONTH}%{TIME_DAY}_%{TIME_HOUR}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/$1_%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MONTH}%{TIME_DAY}_%{TIME_HOUR}.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to lynxman's answer:

In case `%{TIME_MONTH}` doesn't work try with `%{TIME_MON}`:

```
RewriteCond /cache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}_%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}_%{TIME_HOUR}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/$1_%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}_%{TIME_HOUR}.html [L]
```

from: https://craym.eu/tutoriels/referencement/variables_url_rewriting.html